# PDO error: no database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm making a register script and using PDO for the first time, but I get this error when trying to use it. The defines works fine when use MySQLi.

My code gives me this error:

```
Array ( [0] => SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected )
```

This is the code: (/register.php)

```
    try{
        $input_password_hash = password_hash($input_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt = $PDO_new->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = :username");
        $stmt->bindParam(":username",$input_username);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "code after exec";
        //checks if user already exist in database.
        if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
            $error[] = "Username already exist";
            echo "user is there";
        }
        else{
            echo "user not there";
            $insert = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_password_hash, user_email) VALUES($input_username,$input_password_hash, $input_email)";

        }


    } catch(PDOException $e){
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This is the file for connecting to the databse: ((config/db_connect.php)

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config/db.php");
$PDO_new = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";DBName=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$PDO_new->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And this is the file where I define the info for the database: (/config/db.php)

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "username_databasename");
define("DB_USER", "username_admin");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
```

Comment: Why do you have both MySQLi and PDO connections established? They are incompatible.  I'm not sure about case sensitivity in the PDO connection string, but typically it is lowercase: `;dbname=" . DB_NAME`

Comment: Yeah, try changing `DBName` to `dbname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test reveals that a PDO connection is case-sensitive in how it parses attributes.  You use `DBName` when you should be using the lowercase `dbname`.  This is not explicitly stated [in the `PDO::__construct()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), as far as I can tell, but I was able to verify it testing in my own environment.

```
$PDO_new = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
//--------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is unclear why you are also establishing a connection via MySQLi, as MySQLi and PDO are comparable but incompatible APIs. You generally need one or the other, not both (unless you are combining code from 2 sources that use opposite APIs).

It is recommended to wrap the `new PDO()` in a `try/catch` to catch connection errors before setting `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on it.

```
try {
  $PDO_new = new PDO("mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // handle a connection error error
}
```

Finally, I would be remiss if I did not point out that you have plain variables in the `INSERT` statement rather than bound parameters. You should be binding values with placeholders here as you did in the first `SELECT` statement.

```
// Use placeholders please!
$insert = "INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_password_hash, user_email) VALUES(:input_username,:input_password_hash, :input_email)";
// prepare() then execute()...
```

Comment: Ah thanks, i will test this now. 
Just forgot to delete the line with Mysqli as i had that for testing if it worked with mysqli

Comment: Yep it fixed the problem, thank you. 
I can also see now why i changed it to "DBName", it was because i use phpstorm as IDE and I did not like that it said it was a typo when i wrote "dbname" instead of "DBName"

Comment: On behalf of myself and many others I'm sure; thanks for taking the time to test your theory Michael about `dbname` being case-sensitive. +1 on my part. I for one never knew that till now. However, I've always followed the manuals in regards to syntax, but one never knows till one deviates from the norm (ever so slightly), *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I suppose I should add this as a comment on the PDO doc page

Comment: Yes, I agree and highly suggest that you do Michael, it's indeed worthy to be in there. Maybe even a link to your answer also.

Comment: To add and if you want, let me know of the link to the comment you make if you do decide on adding one, and/or include it in your answer so I can vote up on PHP.net @MichaelBerkowski